# Церковное слово

Tags: этимология

Как правильно говорить: требоисправление, требосправление или требосовершение?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, слово "требосправление" есть. Так что, думаю, если Вы так скажете, то не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Сам чуть не попался на этом слове...

Правильно - **требоисправление**. "Исправление" здесь означат именно "справление", "совершение". В современном языке это значение забылось, уступив место "изменению в правильном напрвлении". Но так было далеко не всегда.

**Требосправление** - современный вариант, используется в миру.

Я, конечно, тот еще специалист по ЦСЯ, но тут, вроде, разобрался.
А вот что это за батюшка такой с филологическими задатками?

Comment: Это Воронежская епархия, один из священников Успенского храма

Answer (score 0):

У меня вопрос по  этимологии слова "ТребоИсправление". Есть фраза "Журнал регистрации требоисправлений" мне никак не дается понимание ее. Спрашивал у заведующей кафедрой русской филологии Воронежского государственного университета она подтверждает ваши слова что вернее будет "требоСправление". Смотрел слово "исправить" в словаре церковно славянских слов. Его значение "возвести из одного состояния к другому" "изменить". Спрашивал у священника он говорит что "требоисправление" означает что треба исправляет человека над которым она совершается, очищает его, возводит его из одного состояния в другое. Может кто то может объяснить смысл фразы, есть ли специалисты по церковно славянскому языку??